# Java Thumbnailator saving picture as file

Tags: java, resize, save, thumbnails

I have a picture which I am saving as follows.

```
String outFileThumbnailName = "out_file_name";
File destinationDir = new File(outFileThumbnailName);
Thumbnails.of(outFilename)
  .size(200, 200)
  .outputFormat(null)
  .toFile(destinationDir);
```

I need to save picture as file format.! 
 
However, it is auto saving as JPEG format.

Comment: What is a file format?

Comment: No file format. Just file. In our logic we save pictures without suffix( like .jpg or .png) just its name. However, if you change its format to .jpg (manually) it will work.